# Magento2: Automatically unknown customer have registered in my website

Tags: magento2, recaptcha, customer-registration

I have installed fresh Magento2 setup. Automatically unknown customer  have registered in my website.

What the issue in my website. What do?

Comment: You should set captcha on register page.

Comment: have you tried with added captcha on registration page?

Comment: Ok, I will add captcha @Ravi

Comment: No, I have not added captcha. @Raj